# Opposite of (preceding-sexp)

Tags: emacs

Stupid one, but can't figure it out on my own - how do I get the next sexp? Just like `preceding-sexp`, but forward.

Comment: Nope, that's just movement, not parsing. Btw we follow each other on Twitter, isn't it funny :)

Comment: Indeed :) Well, you know, sharing interests...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into `forward-sexp`. You have a nice example [here](http://sachachua.com/blog/2009/12/behind-the-scenes-livin-la-vida-emacs/).

OK, as per your comment, you don't want just movement, but evaluating the sexp itself. What Sacha did there is this:

```
    (setq start (point))
    (forward-sexp)
    (setq sexp (buffer-substring (point) start))
```

and then `(eval (read sexp))` to eval it. I'll use `buffer-substring-no-properties`, but I'm not sure if this matters in a temporary buffer.

Comment: This is simpler `(progn (forward-sexp) (preceding-sexp))` but it was your answer that made me realise it. Thanks :)